# GNU's parallel utility

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have a bash script which has a while loop which iterates for 32 times writing 1 G file during each iteration using dd command. I can see that it ends up eating all my RAM 32 G in the process and my system freezes. But when i do the same thing using parallel command using -P option like parallel -P 32.This time my memory is not used up. Can some one explain why this is so.

This one is eating up all my memory

```
function exhaust
{


    for item in `seq 1 1 32`
    do
    dd if=/sample/zombie$item of=/dev/null bs=1048576 count=1024 &
    done

    wait

}

exhaust
```

but when i do the following, it run fine

```
function exhaust
{
    dd if=/sample/zombie$item of=/dev/null bs=1048576 count=1024 
}


seq 1 32  | parallel -P 32 exhaust
```

Comment: The idea is that you show your code, not that you ask us why something we can't see doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `&` on both commands. The idea of `GNU Parallel` is that **it** controls what runs in parallel, not you.

As it is, **all** your jobs run simultaneously, rather than `parallel` running a specified number of jobs at once.

Comment: The & in parallel is a typo. Apologies for that. But i dont understand your reason behind asking me to remove & from the other one using for loop and executing dd in background.

Comment: Also, I dont exactly understand when you say parallel running specified jobs at once. You mean to say when i say -P 32, it wont run all 32 simultaneously. When i ps -ef, I can see 32 dd command being executed for both the forms.

Comment: What is $item set to in the parallel case?

Comment: it will be a place holder like item1, item2,item3 so that i write 32 different files, instead of re-doing the same file

Comment: Did you run `export -f exhaust`? You don't show that.

Comment: As it is, you will have 32 processes writing to the same file - which is why your system locks up. You need to pass a parameter to `exhaust` and then pick it up inside the function.

Comment: yes it was there. with out the exhaust cant be used. The snippet is more of a pseudo code of what i was doing. i did this to give an idea as you commented since the original code i am doing is quite big.

Comment: So replace `$item` with `$1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125530/discussion-between-vijay-and-mark-setchell).

Answer (score 0):

(This is not an answer, but it is too long for a comment).

The parallel command is wrong. You probably mean:

```
function exhaust
{
    dd if=/sample/zombie$1 of=/dev/null bs=1048576 count=1024 
}
export -f exhaust

seq 1 32  | parallel -P 32 exhaust
```

($item => $1 and export -f)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments and answers. My original question was whether GNU's parallel will make sure my RAM is not consumed when i spawn multiple threads. The answer is even with parallel we will end up losing all our memory in my case that is dd command whose payload overshoots my RAM size. Looks like file systems like ext3 / ext4 etc dont have any check for memory usage and hence they will eat up all the memory (caching / page caches).